# Запятая между соподчиненными предложениями запятая ставится?

Tags: синтаксис

У Розенталя: 
Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты – союз и соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части;

Разве между соподчиненными ставится запятая? Понятно, что перед *если* нет запятой, так как есть вторая часть союза *если... то*

А если такое будет предложение:

Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и что если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты – союз и соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части;

Здесь перед *и* не нужна запятая?

Comment: На сайте http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm где тоже книга Розенталя, там такого случая вообще нет.

Comment: Зато есть: Слепой знал, что в комнату смотрит солнце и что если он протянет руку в окно, то с кустов посыплется роса (Короленко) (придаточное условное с союзом если нельзя опустить или переставить без перестройки подчиняющего предложения, так как рядом окажутся слова что и то);

Comment: Выходит, если _что_ опустить, то перед _и_ должна появиться запятая?

Comment: на сайте http://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=3445 тоже пытаются получить ответ ответ, почему перед _и_ ставится запятая в предложении о враче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим, что присоединяет И:    Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и (если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты )– ;союз И присоединяет простое предложение к сложноподчинённому.Запятая перед И нужна. Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и что должны выйти из палаты(если мы не хотим тревожить его). Союз И (по смыслу) присоединяет не целое СПП, а только придаточные части  (ЧТО  и ЧТО)- запятая не нужна. ТО нам не мешает, оно влияет на постановку знаков между ЧТО и ЕСЛИ.
Слепой знал, что в комнату смотрит солнце и что с кустов посыплется роса(переставим часть "если он протянет руку в окно", )  - союз и соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части (что и что).

Просто Розенталь говорит в данном случае конкретно о запятой при союзе И. Есть запятая только перед И,если союз И присоединяет целое СПП,придат. часть, однор.чл., а после придаточного есть вторая часть; есть запятая только ПОСЛЕ И, если присоединяет однор. чл. или однородные придаточные и нет второй части; есть запятые и ДО и ПОСЛЕ, если И соединяет простые предложения и после придаточного нет второй части союза.

Розенталь объяснил подробно сочетание трёх союзов, один из которых И.

Comment: Значит, врач сказал только то, что больному нужен покой? А слова остальные  - не его? А если бы врач сказал и о том, что если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты, то запятую надо было бы поставить? 
Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты.

Comment: Я не исключила эту часть предложения, а взяла в скобки присоединяемую конструкцию, как если бы мы составляли схему:[- =], (что = -), и /(если - = ),[то = ]/.Это сложная синтаксическая конструкция, где И относится к СПП.

Comment: Внутри СПП мы можем менять местами главное и придаточное, смысл не изменится, я переставила их местами, чтобы понять, к чему относится союз И.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пишите, что "И присоединяет простое предложение к сложноподчинённому". Но разве Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой - простое предложение?